# $\mathbb{S}^1$-action on $\mathbb S^{2n+1}$

Tags: general-topology, projective-space, separation-axioms

I am trying to show $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is Hausdorff. I came across a proof that I would like to understand.

> Let $[z],[w] \in \mathbb{C}P^{n}$ such that $[z]\ne [w]$ and $z,w \in \mathbb{S}^{2n+1}\subset \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. Note that $\mathbb{S}^1 \subset \mathbb{C}$ is compact so we define $R = \min \{|sz - tw|: s,t \in \mathbb{S}^1\subset \mathbb{C}\} > 0$. Let $U = \{x \in \mathbb{S}^{2n+1}:|x-z| < \frac{R}{2}\}$ and $V = \{x \in \mathbb{S}^{2n+1}:|x-w| < \frac{R}{2}\}$. Note that $\lambda U = U$ and $\lambda V = V$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{S}^1$. So it follows that $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U)) = U$ and $\pi^{-1}(\pi(V))=V$. Thus, $\pi(U)$ and $\pi(V)$ are open and are disjoint, respectively containing $[z]$ and $[w]$. It follows that $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is Hausdorff.

Note that $\pi$ refers to the quotient map. I do not understand why both $U$ and $V$ are invariant under that action of $\mathbb{S}^1$, and to be honest, I do not understand the the aim behind defining $R$ as they have.

Comment: Is $\mathbb S^{n+1}$ supposed to be $S^{2n+1}$?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: This is not true.  I suspect you have misstated something.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I've gone ahead and changed it.

Comment: Maybe I'm a bit confused, but what is the definition of product between an element of $s\in\mathbb{S}^1$ and $z\in\mathbb{S}^{2n+1}$ being used here? Is it supposed to be the product with a 'unit' element of $[z]\in\mathbb{C}P^n$?

Comment: My apologies, I did not clarify, $\mathbb{S}^{2n+1} \subset \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. So complex scalar multiplication to each coordinate.

Comment: I dont think $\lambda \in \mathbb S^n$.

Comment: You're right, it is $\mathbb{S}^1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. The scalar $-1$ is in $\mathbb{S}^1$, but of every $z\in\mathbb{S}^{2n+1}$, $ |z - (-1)z| = 2$. Thus, if $\varepsilon = 1$ for example, $U$ is not stable under the action of $\mathbb{S}^1$.

Comment: Thank you, I've changed my post.